# Include Gutenberg blocks in a Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Is it possible to include a custom Gutenberg block in a Wordpress theme. So that I doesn't have to upload two separate parts: Theme and a plugin with the Gutenberg block.

I have already tried to create a subfolder with the Gutenberg plugin inside the theme and include this one in the functions.php file of my theme. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you're a new contributor; welcome!

The following should work: Put the PHP that registers the block in the theme's **functions.php** file. You'll have to write a function that hooks into the `init` action and does the following:

- uses wp_register_script() to designate a JavaScript file that will act as the template for your block;
- uses register_block_type() to register your block.

That template file, which you would put in the theme alongside functions.php or in a sub-folder, will use JSX to format your block.

Of course, the details of what you code depend on what you want your block to do. I strongly suggest you go through the official [Gutenberg Block Tutorial](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/) from WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! That's exactly what I did. But I excluded these two functions you mentioned in another file. In the theme‘s functions.php I added the line: include 'gutenberg/index.php'; If I upload only the custom Gutenberg Block as a plugin everything works fine. So the Gutenberg Block is correctly coded.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to try it myself. I'll write back if I learn anything useful!

Comment: @mrtf did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @DavidA.French No, unfortunately not. I'm very thankful if you could help me as soon as you have found a solution.

Comment: @mrtf Sure thing. I actually find a fix. Check this pull request on my project to see how someone else helped me do it: https://github.com/jcklpe/common-wp/pull/1